# TCustomEdit right align makes caret position weird

Tags: delphi

I made a number edit (inherited from TCustomEdit) with fixed right alignment:

```
procedure TNumberEdit.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_RIGHT;
end;
```

Works, but the caret posotion looks weird, hiding part of the rightmost character:
[image]
[image]

Tried to set the the right margin with the following code:

```
Perform(EM_SETMARGINS, EC_RIGHTMARGIN, MakeLong(0, xWidth));
```

The margin appears, but doesnt make any difference bot the characters and the caret will get the offset.

How can I prevent this?

(Im using Delphi 7)

Comment: Add an extra space?

Comment: that would be a problem when reading the Text property.

Comment: Of course you have to manage the removal of the extra space when needed.

Comment: Try using a fixed width font and see if that helps.  TrueType fonts allow characters to habe horizontal offsets and to overlap each other ... I don't know if fixed width will help but you could try it.

Comment: you right, it looks OK using fixed width fonts. unfortunately its not a viable solution, but thanks for explaining the problem. maybe I should switch the align to LEFT while the control focused, just as the TDBEdit works.

Comment: I see that you are not using runtime themes. That makes your app look rather ugly in general, and it seems like this problem in particular disappears when you add runtime themes. Since you are using Delphi 7, I think you can drop a `TXPManifest` on your main form to enable themes.

Comment: good idea, but I'm not sure my boss will allow that, there is hundreds of existing forms. anyway, worth to ask, thanks.

Comment: @tcxbalage: You only have to add the `TXPManifest` once, to your main form, and all other forms in the app will automatically use runtime themes as well. You don't have to touch any of the *hundreds of existing forms*, only the main form.

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks I know how it works, it includes a RES file, but still all those forms must be visualy checked, retested and also all the images in the user manual must be updated, not a small job. I already asked my boss, this modification was not allowed by the management.